# How to remove y-axis in a heat map and put the years horizontally

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, heatmap

I'm plotting a heat map and I have the y-axis with two values. The corresponding vertical years are ok (I'd like to put them horizontally too) but by default appeared the years in a way that I can't get rid. How can I remove them and put the remaining years horizontally?

Here is the plot I got and the code below

[image]

```
  # Convert months to factors to re-order them, otherwise they will be sorted alphabetically

  rates_fed$month <- factor(rates_fed$month, levels=c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "June", 
    "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))

  # Plot the data

  rates_fed %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(rate_fed, x = month, y = year)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = rate_fed, width = 3, height = 3)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = rate_fed), color = "white", size = 4) + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c("rate", option = "D", limits=c(0.05, 5.5)) + 
  facet_grid(year~month, scales = "free", space = "fixed", switch = "y")+
  theme_minimal(base_family = "mono")+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11), # change the size according to the viz
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15), # change the size according to the viz
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 15), # change the size according to the viz
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 15), # change the size according to the viz
        plot.title = element_text(size = 15)) + # change the size according to the viz
  labs(x = "month", y = "year",
       title = "Monthly Average Federal Reserve Interest Rates", 
       caption = "Data: Federal Reserve of St. Louis Bank Data")
```

Comment: Do you mean something like `theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you could simply modify the theme:

```
...+theme(axis.text.y = element_blank())
```

I can't test this since I don't have your data. Note that you can use `dput` to convert your data into a format that you can copy/paste.

It looks to me like you probably do not need to bother with `facet_grid`. For your purposes it seems like `geom_tile` should be sufficient.

To rotate a text element you can use the following to rotate it some number of degrees:

```
...+theme(axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))
```

I hope that helps.